# password requirments in twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put password requirements in a twitter bootstrap popover. The content changes as the user types the password. The problem is when its focused on the password field the content changes correctly but when it looses focus and regains focus the content resets itself, while i want it to be as it was before it lost focus. Below is my js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#pass').popover({ 

        placement:'bottom',

        html : true,
        content: function() {
          return $('#pswd_info').html();
        }
      });
$('#pass').keyup(function() {





    var pswd = $(this).val();
    if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
        $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }  
    if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validate capital letter
    if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
        $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validate number
    if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
        $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }


})});
```

Not sure how can achieve this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example..

http://bootply.com/87158

This uses jQuery `.keyup()` for live password validation and displays the message in a Bootstrap popover.

Comment: This not i am looking for i am afraid. I am hoping for the popover contents to change and these changes to be reflected whilst the user is focusing back and forth to the password box.